# Gate and monster appear when returning to Arkham from Other world

Tags: arkham-horror

A gate and a monster appear when returning back to Arkham from Other world.

I want to close the first gate which I came from, so I wait a round.

Does the other gate draw me in next round or can I close the first gate before the other gate draws me in?

Comment: It's a little unclear, but you don't generally have to wait a turn to try to close the gate (although you can certainly retry if you fail the first time) - you should come out of the gate during your movement phase, then attempt to close it during the Arkham encounter phase.

Comment: Also, you say "when returning" but I think you actually mean during the next mythos phase? I know there are encounters that can cause a gate and a monster to appear, but in order to have a normal encounter at that location, there has to not be a gate there. You're not trying to have a normal encounter instead of closing the gate, are you?

Answer (score 8):

I think the "Gate and a monster" effect still needs to follow the basic rules on placing a gate. This means if you are at a location with an Elder Sign, the gate doesn't open, and if you are at a location with an open gate, then a monster surge happens.

So, you are on a location with an open gate, and you have explored it. A gate opens in your location. This means a monster surge happens, and no second gate.

Comment: There can never be 2 gates at the same location at the same time.